# Number of occurrences of each different word in a line of text

Tags: java, beginner

I am looking for feedback on a solution to the following problem posed from a book that I'm working through (*Java: How To Program 9th Edition*):

> Write an application that reads a line of text and prints a table indicating the number of occurrences of each different word in the text. The application should include the words in the table in the same order in which they appear in the text. For example, the lines
>
> To be, or not to be: that is the question:
>   Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
>
> contain the word “to” three times, the word “be” two times, the word “or” once, etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TextAnalysisC {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println( "Please enter a line of text" );
    String userInput = sc.nextLine();

    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

    userInput = userInput.replaceAll( "\\W", " " );     // strip out any non words.
    userInput = userInput.replaceAll( "  ", " " );      // strip out any double spaces
                                                        //   created from stripping out non words
                                                        //   in the first place!
    String[] tokens = userInput.split( " " );
    System.out.println( userInput );

    ArrayList< String > items = new ArrayList< String >();

    items.addAll( Arrays.asList( tokens ) );

    int count = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++ )
    {
        System.out.printf( "%s: ", items.get( i ) );
        for( int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++ )
        {
            if( items.get( i ).equals( items.get( j ) ) )
                count++;
            if( items.get( i ).equals( items.get( j ) ) && count > 1 )
                items.remove( j );                      // after having counted at least
        }                                               // one, remove duplicates from List        
        System.out.printf( "%d\n", count );
        count = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Can this be simplified?  Is this easy to understand?  What should I improve?

I regret to report that I have been remiss on the current scope of my knowledge as I work through my textbook (*Java: 9th Edition*). Solutions should be within the limits of what I have covered so far, that being:

1. Introduction to Computers and Java
2. Introduction to Java Applications
3. Introduction to Classes, Objects, Methods and Strings
4. Control Statements: Part 1
5. Control Statements: Part 2
6. Methods: A Deeper Look
7. Arrays and ArrayLists
8. Classes and Objects: A Deeper Look
9. Object-Oriented Programming: Inheritance
10. Object-Oriented Programming: Polymorphism
11. Exception Handling: A Deeper Look
12. GUI Components: Part 1 (Swing)
13. Strings, Characters and Regular Expressions

Comment: your code has a bug. Try to give `a b b b c` as input and see the result.

Comment: oh hell yes, well spotted @tintinmj, I think it has something to do with the line `items.remove( j )` reordering the sequence of letters in the ArrayList.  I think it could be confusing things, I'll try and fix it in the morning.  A better algorithm might be in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a `LinkedHashMap``<String,`[`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)`>`, adding the words in order.

`LinkedHashMap` is a `Map`, so duplicate keys can easily be detected. `AtomicInteger` will allow incrementing the value without having to replace the value in the `Map`. Yet AtomicInteger isn't exactly intended to be used as a dumb counter, making your own `Counter` class is also a good option, as long as it has an `increment()` and a `get()` method, it'll make your interaction with the Map a lot smoother.

You can use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to break up the input String in words.

Quick pseudo code:

```
split input String into words
loop the words
   if word not in map
      add word as key, with new counter
   get counter for word and increment
loop map entries
   print word and number of occurrences
```

***Edit***

Given the scope of your knowledge, I'll make a suggestion that only uses what you should know already. The idea is to replace the Map by an ArrayList of words and a matching array of int to hold the counts.

```
split input String into words
initialize an int[] array with the size equal to the number of words // max needed capacity
initialize an ArrayList of Strings
loop the words
   determine index of the word in ArrayList.
   if word not in ArrayList
      add word to ArrayList
   increment int in array at matching index as the word in the ArrayList
loop ArrayList
   print word and number of occurrences (from same index in array)
```

Comment: as a beginner I haven't covered these topics yet, (see edit above) my apologies for the lack of clarity.  However I shall revisit your contribution when I come to the appropriate chapter and absorb your solution at that time.

Comment: That's ok, but the scope of this site is however larger.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways of doing this problem:

1. Using a `HashMap<String, Integer>`, read each line and split the words and test to see if the `HashMap` contains a particular word. If not, then insert it, else, increment the value. This will require us to compute the HashCode which can be done in \$O(N)\$ and the search for a HashMap in \$O(1)\$.
2. Use a dictionary/symbol table BST with a key and value inside all nodes. Search and insert is done in a \$log(N)\$ time. For a given word we can search the BST and insert if the key is not found. If found, update the counter in the node. The space taken will be proportional to number of words in the book.
3. Perhaps the most efficient and scalable answer is to simply use a database table with two columns (name, value). Consider millions or billion of words. There is no easy or elegant way to keeping that much data in memory inside a `HashMap` or a BST. For every word, do a see if it exists in the table. If not, insert it, else, update the counter.

Comment: thanks @Jamal i was just about to correct the HashSet to HashMap

Answer (score 0):

Both calls to replaceAll and the call to split could be replaced by 1 call to split. Remember that split accepts a regex and that regex patterns can endlessly combine matches for "one or more occurrences" of another pattern with matches for "one pattern or another", etc.

In any case, your regex usage would have to be a little more complicated if you wanted to support words like "don't".

Your counting algorithm does not scale up well for large inputs -- it's "O(n-squared)",
and it uses a lot of custom code to make an ArrayList do the work of a more functional collection class.
What you want is one scan over your tokens to build up a smarter collection of tokens with their running counts.
For that, you want a collection that lets you efficiently find the running count for an "old" token without serially scanning for the token among all the tokens so far.
After that, you can make one pass over the collection to print your output.
That means that you want the collection to preserve the order in which you added each token.

There's a collection class for that. It's name currently escapes me. It'd probably be instructive for you to research it, anyway, since this is an educational project.

Comment: hey user1542234, the book I'm using doesn't seem to show how to do this with split(), I tried split.(" \\s*") to no avail.  Searching for more info.  I've not fully covered Collections yet, still a few chapters away, sorry for the lack of clarity (see edit above).